# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseException

Tags: android, gradle, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I encountered a problem with the Firebase integration. First of all, I have added rules to the root-level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the module Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.9"
    }
    buildTypes {
       ///
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

During the build of the project, I get the error:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseException;

Error reason is clear, but I didn't compile any library twice. Should I exclude `FirebaseException` class from the build process manually? If so, how? Perhaps this is a bug within the Firebase dependencies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

I had this problem with `react-native-google-signin` module. As the instructions how to modify `build.gradle` are often not up to date, incomplete or just defined in multiple unrelated projects the project compiled only after copying the settings from the `react-native-google-signin` example project. It turns out the order of statements is important as well as `exclude group` command. The final result looked like this (in `app/build.gradle`):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    }   
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile
   into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The top `build.gradle` included an additional `gms` classpath as usual:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

After these changes build finished without any `Multiple dex` errors.

Comment: Also had this problem for react-native-push-notification library

Comment: Also had this due to `react-native-maps` from AirBnB.

Comment: Thanks, i have created a PR => https://github.com/joonhocho/react-native-google-sign-in/pull/25

Answer (score 5):

FireBase is a huge library, so you need to enable multidex support in your application.

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2') {
        exclude module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

defaultConfig {
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!!!!
I encountered the issue while using RNFirebase's Firestore

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have reached [methods count limit](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html). Try to remove `firebase` dependencies and check methods count for your app (for example, with [this gradle plugin](https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin) (if you don't remove these dependencies you won't be able to build your project at all, thus, to use the methods count plugin).

Firebase [is a HUGE library](http://www.methodscount.com/?lib=com.google.firebase%3Afirebase-core%3A9.0.2) - 17k+ methods. It depends on tons of stuff. One thing you can do is to check dependencies list by clicking this button on "methodscount.com":
[image]

If you already have some of these in your project you can try to exclude them:

```
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2') {
    exclude module: 'play-services-base'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

If this doesn't help then you might want to [configure multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle) for you project.

Answer (score 2):

I am using **react-native-maps** and **react-native-google-signin.**

And, I got **Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseException**

Bellow my solution.

Open build.gradle (react-native-maps)

```
dependencies {
     provided "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
     compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.4"
     compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4"
}
```

The version is 10.2.4

Continue open build.gradle (react-native-google-signin)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1' <- change here
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}
```

It uses version 9.2.1, and this is reason.

Change it to version 10.2.4 will be

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4'
```

Next, open build.gradle (app) and add a new one

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4'
```

Now you have.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4'
compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" 
}
```

Run command `cd android & gradlew clean & cd ..`  util no error then run `react-native run-android`.
Hope can help.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone, I was hitting a similar problem, it was caused by the Gradle plugin for Google services bringing in a dependency which conflicted with Firebase.

In my top level build.gradle I had, in buildscript:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Which was bringing in (automatically) dependencies which were conflicting with, in my app's build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.2.0'
```

Little bit confusing as I only had one compile dependency and was scratching my head what could be conflicing.

I removed the google-services gradle plugin and it solved the issue. I suppose I could also just find the right version :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I was using firebase-ui:2.0.0. I managed to solve it by downgrading to `'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'` and added the following line in Project level build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        // Add the following
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41518731/3994630), just check and upgrade your google dependencies versions to the last release.

> I could fix my problem. The problem was that BaseGameUtils was still
>   using/referencing an older version of play-services. Added the correct
>   version, and it works now. Guess I will omit BaseGameUtils for my next
>   project.

Answer (score 0):

This is because some of your libraries use different versions of other library.

Check out your last added library and exclude.
For my project that was 'react-native-firestack'.

```
compile(project(':react-native-firestack')){
     exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please add this code inside android in build.gradle

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

Comment: Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted